# The children component beyond the parent view cannot respond to onPress() events on android platform

Tags: android, react-native, overflow

The part of outside the parent component cannot respond to events on android platform.

Two Components: The parent component and the children component.
The part of children component, which outside the parent component, the `onPress` function cannot execute.
[image: Where the red box is not responding]
The code is:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Text, TouchableOpacity,View, StyleSheet, TouchableNativeFeedback, TouchableWithoutFeedback } from 'react-native'

export default class GroupPage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            visible: false
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}
            >
                <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={()=>{console.log('the parent component click');}}
                >
                    <View style={styles.largeStyle}
                    >
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{console.log('the children component click');}}

                    >
                        <View 
                           style={styles.smallStyle} 
                            // pointerEvents='box-only'
                        >
                        </View>               
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
    largeStyle: {
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        backgroundColor: 'skyblue',
    },
    smallStyle: {
        zIndex: 1,
        elevation: 20,
        position: 'relative',
        // top: -20,
        // right: -20,
        marginTop: -20,
        width: 50,
        height: 50,
        backgroundColor: 'orange',
    }
})
```

The part of outside the parent component can respond to events on android platform.

Comment: Is that the prop code you're showing me?

Comment: Please show both parent and child component

Comment: @hongdevelop @IanStebanVasco  How can I update a picture? When I update a picture. It`s not show.